# Excel value counting

Tags: excel, excel-2007

This morning i am faced with yet another excel problem.

I have a data set, a sample of the data is below. My data is linked to a dialer for a call center. So we have an Hour column which is the hour that call was made eg. 7 = 7am and so forth, there is a ring duration column which is the duration the phone rang for and we have a direction, which is the final end of the call (e.g. was the call valid and did we make right party contact or was the call invalid).

```
Hour    Ring Duration   Directions
10      1               4
7       1               3
10      0               5
9       1               3
13      0               3
10      0               4
16      0               5
```

What i want to do is count all the valid calls and invalid calls for for an hour. Below i have made another small table that has each hour, the valid lead for that call and the invalids, now here is where my problem starts.

all the calls with a direction of 5 is a valid call and the rest are invalid, i need to count for each hour the amount of direction 5's we have and i also need too count the rest for invalid. How would i go about doing this?

Here is my other table that im not sure how to do:

```
Hour    Total Valid     Total Invalid
7       
8       
9       
10      
11      
12      
13      
14      
15      
16
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$5:$A$156, 7,$C$5:$C$156,5)
```

$A$5:$A$156 is the hour column on my sheet and 7 is the hour im checking against, $C$5:$C$156 is the direction and 5 is my criteria so it works out like that.